# How to build a date time regex to replacing?

Tags: python, regex

In a python script I need to format a string.

What I've got:

```
em|2017-08-24|PE|TETE|USD||AR|2017-08-25 06:54:40|-98.58
```

I'm looking for:

```
em|2017/08/24|PE|TETE|USD||AR|2017/08/25:06:54:40|-98.58
```

Pay attention to replace `"/"` instead of `"-"`
and `":"` in the middle instead of `" "` on a datetime value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `re.sub()` function:

```
import re

# replacement callback
def repl(m):
    sep = m.group(4)   # ending separator
    sep = sep if sep == '|' else ':'
    return '%s/%s/%s%s' % (m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), sep)

s = 'em|2017-08-24|PE|TETE|USD||AR|2017-08-25 06:54:40|-98.58'
result = re.sub(r'(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})(\||\s)', repl, s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
em|2017/08/24|PE|TETE|USD||AR|2017/08/25:06:54:40|-98.58
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string doesn't contain other dash preceded by a word boundary and no other spaces, you can use:

```
re.sub(r'\b-', '/', s).replace(' ', ':')
```

However Roman's answer is more appropriate if the lines don't always fit these conditions.